# loading file into js variable in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I need, in a js file (app/assets/javascripts/projects.js.coffee), to load into a variable the content of a file. The file is now stored at app/templates but I can move it elsewhere if a different location will make it work.

I tried

```
$.get "app/templates/project.txt", (template) ->
  console.log template
```

Just to see, as first step, if the file was loaded but I get

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/app/templates/project.txt 404 (Not Found)
```

What's the right way to achieve so?

Thanks

Comment: if it's a static file then move it to either `public` or `app/assets` or if it's a dynamic data then serve it from your controller. for example in your `index` action of `ProjectsController` you may have `respond_to {|format| format.html {..}; format.txt {..}}` etc

Comment: or if you simply want to bootstrapped to your page then just put in your erb template like `var somevar = <%= @xyz.to_json.html_safe %>;`

Comment: I really don't wanna put stuff in public.  My goal is avoiding to pass too much data from controller to view so I wish to pass only json and render the template using jquery on the client.

Comment: let's say I put my template in app/assets/templates. How can I access it later on? Just doing _$.get"app/assets/templates/project.txt"_?  Thanks again

Comment: Is it a static data or a dynamic? If it's static yes you can just put it in `app/assets` if it's dynamic then no you should serve it properly from your controller.

Comment: It is static. Right now it is a txt file but I will update it soon using a mustache template.  Thanks

Comment: Put them in ``app/assets`` but nothing changed. Do I have to add anything in the sprockets manifest?